# Dynamically update equation using vectors

Tags: r, function, if-statement, vector

I was hoping to automate the following process but have been unable to find a solution. The aim is to use vectors `height` and `area` to update each `if` equation in the function. The function would then use depth (x) to convert to volume.

The equation for each `if statement` would use the following syntax:

```
for (i in 2:length(height) {

(x >= height[i - 1] &&
               x <= height[i]) {
      (((area[i] - area[i - 1]) * (x - height[i - 1]) / 
          (height[i] - height[i - 1]) + area[i - 1]) * x)
}
```

Manual method:

```
height <- c(0.01, seq(0.05, 0.5, by = 0.05))
area <- c(8, 210, 300, 350, 400, 440, 470, 500, 535, 570, 610)

# Height values
Hmin <- min(height)
Hmax <- max(height)

for(i in 2:(length(height) - 1)) {
  assign(paste0("H", i-1), height[i])
}

# Area values
Amin <- min(area)
Amax <- max(area)

for(i in 2:(length(area) - 1)) {
  assign(paste0("A", i-1), area[i])
}

volume.fn <- function(x) {
  if (x < Hmin) {                                             # if less than min height value 
    x <- 0                                                    # x <- 0 
  } else if (x >= Hmin &&                                     # if between min height and next height value
             x <= H1) {
    (((A1 - Amin) * (x - Hmin) / (H1 - Hmin) + Amin) * x)     # apply this linear interpolation equation to depth column (x)
  } else if (x >= H1 &&                                       # if x between height1 and height 2 
             x <= H2) {
    (((A2 - A1) * (x - H1) / (H2 - H1) + A1) * x)             # apply this linear interpolation equation to depth column (x)
  } else if (x >= H2 &&
             x <= H3) {
    (((A3 - A2) * (x - H2) / (H3 - H2) + A2) * x)
  } else if (x >= H3 &&
             x <= H4) {
    (((A4 - A3) * (x - H3) / (H4 - H3) + A3) * x)
  } else if (x >= H4 &&
             x <= H5) {
    (((A5 - A4) * (x - H4) / (H5 - H4) + A4) * x)
  } else if (x >= H5 &&
             x <= H6) {
    (((A6 - A5) * (x - H5) / (H6 - H5) + A5) * x)
  } else if (x >= H6 &&
             x <= H7) {
    (((A7 - A6) * (x - H6) / (H7 - H6) + A6) * x)
  } else if (x >= H7 &&
             x <= H8) {
    (((A8 - A7) * (x - H7) / (H8 - H7) + A7) * x)
  } else if (x >= H8 &&
             x <= H9) {
    (((A9 - A8) * (x - H8) / (H9 - H8) + A8) * x)
  } else if (x >= H9 &&
             x <= Hmax) {
    (((Amax - A9) * (x - H9) / (Hmax - H9) + A9) * x)
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `findInterval` you could do:

```r
volume.fn1 <- function(x, height, area) {
  volume <- if (x < min(height)) {
    0
  } else if (x > max(height)) {
    NA
  } else {
    i <- findInterval(x, height, rightmost.closed = TRUE) + 1
    ((area[i] - area[i - 1]) * (x - height[i - 1]) /
      (height[i] - height[i - 1]) + area[i - 1]) * x
  }

  return(volume)
}

volume.fn(.32)
#> [1] 154.24

volume.fn1(.32, height, area)
#> [1] 154.24

volume.fn(.48)
#> [1] 285.12

volume.fn1(.48, height, area)
#> [1] 285.12
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan that works really well and exactly what I wanted to achieve!